# The view blog.views.contacto didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: django, forms, view, httpresponse

I´m working on my first django project. I´ve been trying to create a simple contact form, but I get the error:

ValueError at /blog/contacto/
The view blog.views.contacto didn't return an HttpResponse object.

```
def contacto (request):
if request.method == 'POST': #Si e formulario es enviado...
    form = Formulario(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid(): #Si son validos los datos del formulario
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/gracias') #redireccion a gracias
    else:
        form = Formulario() #un Unbound form

    return render(request, 'contacto.html',{'form':form,})
```

I don´t understand why this is happening, I´ve checked the forms documentation in django and the view I´ve done is almost identical to the one in the documentation.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view doesn't return an `HttpResponse` if `request.method` is not `POST`.

There is an indentation issue. You need to return an *unbound form* in case the form is not submitted:

```
def contacto (request):
    if request.method == 'POST': #Si e formulario es enviado...
        form = Formulario(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): #Si son validos los datos del formulario
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/gracias') #redireccion a gracias
    else:  # <-- WATCH WHERE ELSE IS
        form = Formulario() #un Unbound form

    return render(request, 'contacto.html',{'form':form,})
```

Also see this [relevant example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view) that describes this standard form view pattern.